# Messages take longer to send on WIFI even with a higher link speed

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I am working on a program that communicates with an industrial device via a TCP network connection.

The program uses a library provided by the manufacturer, from what I understand of the underlying protocol I am sending messages (<50 bytes) that the controller responds with messages around 16kB.

I am having issues where when using a WIFI connection (Full signal strength N connection 433Mbs/s) the messages take too long, around 100ms. With exactly the same software the same message takes around 20ms over a 100Mb/s wired connection.

If I ping the device I consistently get 1ms on either connection method.

I don't understand the lower level differences too much, but what factors are there that can cause a connection with a higher link speed to respond slower (even when both have a comparable ping).

Are there any connection settings I can adjust to try and bring down the time a message takes to be received when using a wireless connection.

Comment: Interference is my first thought. Either from other APs in the area, fluorescent lights, industrial motors, metal walls/studs, anything else that might emit a high EMF. Directional antennas may help. Placement of the AP and client is important. You mention the signal strength is good, and ping is showing no drops. Can you verify the RF hostility between the transmitting station and client? Maybe also check the all network interfaces for CRC errors, which often are generated by some physical issue. A packet sniffer may give you details about the transmission status and potential issues.

Comment: Generally, wired ethernet is always going to be faster (less latency) and more reliable than any Wifi connection, despite the advertised Wifi speed, which is likely to only hit top speed in bursts.

Comment: I know Ethernet will generally be more reliable, this is a connection between a controller and a windows tablet used for diagnostics and trending data. Total bandwidth requirement is around 2 Mb/s. Absolute timing isn't too important as we are reading data out that is buffered, and just need to keep pulling data out fast enough to keep the buffer from filling (Full buffer length is around 5s)

Comment: In terms of interference this testing is being carried out in our workshop, there are no motors, VSDs or other high power noisy loads around, and the only competing Wifi network is our office network which is on a different channel. For what its worth this also occur across two different access points (one an expensive industrial oriented AP, and one a cheap Pocket AP)

Comment: Do you have the option to try 5GHz instead of 2.4GHz? Latency is far better in the 5GHz range. When testing, is the performance consistent, or variable (always 100ms)? Verify the transmission power of the Access Point radio is on its highest setting. Experiencing the same issue on two different APs may indicate its just Wifi overhead. My definition of overhead would be how Wifi handles collision avoidance, and TCP retransmissions. A packet capture can help diagnose that further, checking for TCP retries, malformed packets, etc. Compare wired capture to wifi capture.

Comment: Do you mind posting the software libraries and hardware you are using to see if we can glean any information from the nets from people who may have experienced similar problems?

Comment: When testing, You can also increase your ping byte size with "ping -l #### <ip address>", replacing the # with the size in bytes. This will allow ping to give you a more accurate picture of a real data transmit. Testing this on my own systems, where I have 5GHz wifi, hardwired gigabit, and close proximity to everything, I get these results > https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPytc.png Transmitting 1000 bytes over the wire is nothing, and on wifi it takes around 140ms on average. Without customizing a high grade AP and directional antennas, I don't think this can get better.

Comment: The library I am using is RMCLink to connect to an RMC200 Motion controller https://deltamotion.com/products/software/rmclink.php and my software is in c# running on a surface pro 7 for production or my laptop (gigabyte aero 15w) for development. I have got a packet capture of each interface https://www.dropbox.com/s/e67edm2gz20klbm/captures.zip?dl=0 I would skip to the middle of each file (there will be a bit of setup at the start of the capture). I am not really experienced with these captures, I note the messages are getting broken up into smaller packets, and time deltas are very different

Comment: I have tried 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz with no major changes <5% difference. I didnt know you could adjust the ping size, I will check and report back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112190/discussion-between-jim-diroff-ii-and-hugoagogo).

Comment: Did you make a wireless network analysis? Will your final wireless network environnement be under total control?